tkcalendar with ttkbootstrap compatibility issues
I am using ttkbootstrap in my python script. I tried using the DateEntry from ttkbootstrap, but it does not fire an event like tkcalendar does (at least i couldnt find anything to it) and i like that there is a week-counter on the side of tkcalendar.
So i would like to use tkcalendar DateEntry instead of the ttkbootstrap DateEntry. Now on their own it works perfectly, but not when i use ttkbootstrap and tkcalendar together i always get

AttributeError: 'DateEntry' object has no attribute '_calendar'

Here's my code that does NOT work:
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

#setup the window
pwin = ttk.Window(themename="cyborg")
pwin.title('test')

#function to get the date
def seedate():
    print(cal.get_date())

#this is he DateEntry widget
cal =  DateEntry(pwin,bootstyle="info")
cal.place(x=10, y=80)

#button to get the selected date
btnpt = ttk.Button(pwin, text="Save Schedule", bootstyle="light-outline", command=seedate)
btnpt.place(x=10, y=140)

pwin.mainloop()


When I use the ttkbootstrap DateEntry instead, it works instantly.
I tried to update both modules,but it didn't work. And to switch to the ttkbootstram DateEntry, then it works.


So i would like to use tkcalendar DateEntry instead of the
ttkbootstrap DateEntry. Now on their own it works perfectly, but not
when i use ttkbootstrap and tkcalendar together i always get



AttributeError: 'DateEntry' object has no attribute '_calendar'


The problem can be fixed:
Edit: With ttkbootstrap:

On line 11, set the indentation.

Also change this:
print(cal.get_date())

to:
print(cal.entry.get())

Screenshot:

Edit: Without ttkbootstrap:
Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

#setup the window
pwin = tk.Tk()
pwin.title('test')

#function to get the date
def seedate():
    print(cal.get_date())

#this is he DateEntry widget
cal =  DateEntry(pwin)
cal.place(x=10, y=80)

#button to get the selected date
btnpt = tk.Button(pwin, text="Save Schedule",  command=seedate)
btnpt.place(x=10, y=140)

pwin.mainloop()

Screenshot:


oh that probably got deleted during copying it. it does not work even though its indented. I also tried it on a compleatly different device that has no connections to my one and it also does not work there.
Are you sure you use the DateEntry from tkcalendar and not the DateEntry from ttkbootstrap?

Yes I got it working. Did you change this to print(cal.entry.get())?

From the screenshot, it is obviously that ttkbootstrap.DateEntry is used instead of tkcalendar.DateEntry.

okay @toyotaSupra then you missunderstood me. the cal.entry.get() is not possible with tkcalendar DateEntry, you are using the DateEntry from ttkbootstrap. That also works for me, but i want to use the tkcalendar DateEntry https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html

Then you will have to remove ttkbootstrap. In order to get is working
